# Should the tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock be symlinked for capistrano deploys of our unicorn server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sockets, deployment, capistrano, unicorn

I have deployed a rails app on unicorn, and am using Capistrano to manage deployment. Is it a good idea to symlink the `tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock` file to file in the `shared` directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a file that links two system processes, your app server and your web server.

I would definitely do put it at least under the *shared* directory or even better under /var file system.

If you leave it under *current* directory it is in fact bound to a particular deployment release.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am doing as of now. You said that you'd put it in the /var file system, how would you manage this if you had multiple unicorn instances running for different web apps on the same machine?

Comment: Can they be put in different directories? Says put them in "/var/run/unicorn/#{application}"

Comment: yes. if you have several unicorns running diferent apps, it makes sense.